# OpenCTI Screen Pop only when window is in focus

Tags: apex, javascript, opencti

We have an in-house OpenCTI adapter that we use with salesforce. It's primary responsibility is to find associated records and pop the results when a new call comes in.

We have a tendency to have Salesforce open in a number of tabs at once. We quickly found that screen popping in all of these windows was not what we desired.

Our hope is to limit the screen pop to only the currently focused window. Because our JS is operating from within the OpenCTI iframe, we aren't finding an easy way to do this.

Is anyone aware of a way to detect whether the current window/tab is in focus from the OpenCTI iframe? Is there some Salesforce OpenCTI method (or APEX method) that can achieve this?